# How can a GPS with damaged screen be put to use?

Tags: diy, gps

I bought a Holux 260 Pro last year but it fell off the bike on very first day, due to faulty clamp. Sending it to the company for replacement is very costly(>50% of the device cost) so it's been lying around for over a year.
Except for the broken screen, the device is fully functional. I can't use it normally as the screen is totally damaged. Anybody having some good ideas to put it to a good use?

Comment: Since it looks like it has physical buttons,  you could probably get someone with the same GPS to figure out the key sequence needed to do the required functions such as reset trip recording, and save current trip.  Then you could plug it into your computer (looks like it has USB) to view your trip information afterwards. It probably uses standard format that can be imported into Strava, MapMyRide, or Google Earth.  It probably wouldn't be much use while riding without the screen, and you'd risk missing out on the recording if you pushed the wrong key sequence.

Comment: If you don't get great answers here and are open to the idea of using it for something other than cycling, you might consider migrating this question to http://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: You might check with local cellphone repair outfits to see if they can fix it.

Comment: Door stop comes to mind.  Problem is the amount of shagging around it would be easier to just buy a GPS. A cheap second hand android phone and some free software goes a long way.

Comment: It may be possible to find a second hand unit that has been damaged in some other way, but still has an operative screen, and perform the swap. (I did this a couple of times with blackberry phones, don't know specifically for your gps unit though...)

Comment: @DanielRHicks suggestion sounds like a good thing to do. I didn't think of it before but if they can replace the screen, that'd be perfect.

Comment: @Jahaziel's suggestion also seems sound though a bit of a problem to track it down.

Answer (score 1):

I'd figure out the key combinations to start and stop recording, and enable .gpx track recording.

You could then plug it into a computer and extract the .gpx files, and then use tools to play with them:

1. http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/ will let you upload the file and view it on a map
2. http://gpxdataanalyzer.com/ is a site I wrote that will analyze the file and return some analysis on it if you pick an activity (Flying, Driving, Hiking, etc.) I should probably add bicycling.
3. Any number of tools (including the Garmin software that comes with their GPS units) that will allow you to visualize the data 'off device'.